# Make each "Read more" event click displays data not at the same time in an HTML table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am fetching data from a SQL table to be displayed in an HTML table. The problem is that I want to keep the data in "Read More" event so that the table will not be messy.

Since I am fetching the data by rows, I use class name at JQuery. How do  I make "Read More" event works not all rows at one time ? Here's my code.

```js
$('[class^="text1"]').hide();

$('button[class^="toggle1"]').click(function() {
  var elem = $('#toggle').text();
  if (elem == "Read More") {
    //alert('hiii');
    //Stuff to do when btn is in the read more state
    $('button[class^="toggle1"]').text("Read Less");
    $('.text1').slideDown();
  } else {
    //Stuff to do when btn is in the read less state
    $('button[class^="toggle1"]').text("Read More");
    $('.text1').slideUp();
  }
});
```

```html
<td width="30%"><label>
    <p id="text" class='text1'><?php echo ($row['StartDate'] )?></p> 
    <button type='button' id="toggle" class='toggle1' style="background: 
    none; border:none; padding: 0; cursor: pointer; border-bottom:1px solid 
    #444;">Read More</button>     
  </label>
</td>
```

I was expecting the code would be like:

```
each.$('button[class^="toggle1"]').click(function() {
```

so that not all "Read More" event will be triggered at the same time.

This is the example of my work:

[image]

Comment: you can use $(Selector).html("ajax success data"); event to get that within define div on click and then you can also hide it by making $selector.html(" ");

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have many rows that their 'id' and 'class' tags are similar. In that case you'd rather need a for loop to create them which will create unique id/class for every row so that you can access from your Jquery regex matcher an identifier that matches only one row or id / class.

Comment: yes that's my main problem here. I'll try to use your suggestion. Many thanks !